# react-native run-android command throws "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out" error

Tags: android, react-native

I have just installed Android Studio and configured everything as [given in official docs](http://%20https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

I have install nodejs using chocolatey. Python27 and JDK10 were already installed.

I am using Windows 10, my internet connect is working (I have tried it with two different WiFi connections, and with no internet it gives a different error)

I have tried running `cmd` as admin, but with no luck

```
C:\react_native_apps\SecondProject>react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:52)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:52)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\react_native_apps\SecondProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\react_native_apps\SecondProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:137:41)
    at C:\react_native_apps\SecondProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:103:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\react_native_apps\SecondProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:166:7)
```

Comment: I have exact same error.  Are you perhaps behind corporate firewall as well?  I am and I'm wondering if this is contributing factor here.

Comment: Looks like you might need gradle properties file.  I will post if I get it working.

Comment: I am not behind a firewall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try manually downloading that zip (just paste the link the the zip in browser) and place the dl'ed zip in your projects 'android\gradle\wrapper' folder.  Then update the gradle-wrapper.properties file in that same folder.  Update the property `distributionURL` to point at that zip you copied in this folder.

So an example would be like:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

This is a workaround that is working for us.